# Childhood Memories

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> I often make young kids feel better
>   The name most know me by is just 4 letters
>   Take off the last letter of that name and it might smell bad
>   One of my friends is always sad
>   Pinning the tail on that friend is a fun game
>   A horse could say part of my full name
>   My favorite food is quite hard to get
>   And retrieving it often causes a fit
>   The color of my fur is synonymous for wanting to hide
>   And I want to do just that at nighttide

Who am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Winnie the Pooh.

I often make young kids feel better

The name most know me by is just 4 letters

> Winnie the Pooh is a character from Disney media, often known as just as "Pooh".

Take off the last letter of that name and it might smell bad

> Poo would certainly smell bad.

One of my friends is always sad
Pinning the tail on that friend is a fun game

> His friend, Eeyore, is a sad donkey; people commonly play the game of "pin the tail on the donkey" at children's birthday parties.

A horse could say part of my full name

> Horses whinny, which sounds like the first name, "Winnie".

My favorite food is quite hard to get
And retrieving it often causes a fit

> His favorite food is honey - it's very easy to anger bees if you don't know what you're doing.

The color of my fur is synonymous for wanting to hide

> "Yellow" means "cowardly".

And I want to do just that at nighttide

> Pooh is scared of the dark.

Comment: +1, wouldn't have gotten the yellow + nighttime references